# How do I fix a VBA Runtime Error 13 Type Mismatch?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to combine a bunch of smaller VBA codes to create a string of processes to be completed in succession. I'm close, but an error message: Run Time Error '13': Type mismatch comes up and when I go to Debug, it highlights "For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)." This is towards the end of the processes - the last step which is to separate the current sheet into two new sheets based on the values in a particular column.

```
Sub Assessments_Clean_1()

[A:A].Select

With Selection
    .NumberFormat = "General"
    .Value = .Value
End With

Columns("D:D").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("D:D").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("F:F").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("G:G").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("G1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Next Step"
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=IF(RC[-1]="""",""Assessments_Clean_2"",IF(RC[-1]<DATE(2023,7,1),""Delete"",IF(RC[-1]>=DATE(2023,7,1),""Completed_Orig"")))"

Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set rng = ws.Range("G2:G" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
ws.Range("G2").AutoFill Destination:=rng
rng.Select
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False

Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
For i = Last To 1 Step -1
    If (Cells(i, "G").Value) = "Delete" Then
        Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i

Dim lr As Long
Dim icol As Long
Dim myarr As Variant
Dim title As String
Dim titlerow As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

vcol = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Which column would you like to filter by?", title:="Filter column", Default:="1", Type:=1)

Set ws = ActiveSheet
lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
title = "A1"
titlerow = ws.Range(title).Cells(1).Row
icol = ws.Columns.Count
ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"

For i = 2 To lr
    On Error Resume Next
    If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And 
        Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
        ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
    End If
Next

myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
ws.Columns(icol).Clear

For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
    ws.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
    If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
        Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
    Else
        Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    End If

    ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
    'Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit
Next

ws.AutoFilterMode = False
ws.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Start by commenting out that `On Error Resume Next` - with that in place, it's impossible to debug your code.   And please don't double-space your code when posting - it makes it a lot more difficult to can through since it's so sparse.

Comment: Have a look at the dimensions of `myarr` after it got filled in, I'm having a sneaking suspicion it'll have 2 dimensions, not just the one since you also have 2 when you get the values from a range without the transposing part, i.e. `myarr = Range("A1:A10").Value` will have (1 To 10, 1 To 1) as the bounds.

Comment: Some errors have been introduced with the reformatting - original post didn't have `\[A:A\].Select`.  It was just `[A:A].Select`

Comment: @TimWilliams - Sorry about the double space - it pasted that way and I didn't fix. Will go through and delete all the spaces next time. Where would I add "On Error Resume Next" in the code?

Comment: Don't use `On Error Resume Next` unless you're aware of a possible error happening and being ok if it gets ignored. Also use `On Error GoTo 0` as early as possible after it, i.e. `On Error Resume Next : Set rng = Range("A1:A10").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) : On Error GoTo 0` since it will error if there are no visible cells at the time of setting the range. @DarrenBartrup-Cook thanks for bringing it up, removed the backslashes.

Comment: Also, I guess overall, the question is why doesn't the code work when strung together when all the separate pieces do work? I'm using the same data set for testing.

Comment: Have you checked yet what your `myarr` looks like yet?

Comment: `myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))` you can't pick up an array from a range which is not a contiguous range (ie. the range can only have a single area)

Answer (score 1):

### VBA Code Revision

**Refactoring**

- Refactoring is a process in which you split a long code into smaller codes that will be easier to read and maintain and possibly reusable. You are (I am) doing the opposite. I would encourage you to post the following code (once you get it to work as desired) on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) and ask to refactor it so you can see what it should look like i.e. one reasonably short (main) procedure (sub) that you will run, calling the other (helper) procedures (subs or functions).

**Revised**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Assessments_Clean_2()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    sws.AutoFilterMode = False ' turn off auto-filtering
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.UsedRange
    
    ' The code in the following If statement can run only once!!!
    
    If srg.Range("G1").Value <> "Next Step" Then ' or find another way
    
        ' Reset number format and convert formulas to values in column 'A'.
        With srg.Columns("A")
            .NumberFormat = "General"
            .Value = .Value
        End With
        ' Delete columns 'D', 'E' and 'H'.
        sws.Range("D:E,H:H").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        ' Insert column 'G'.
        sws.Columns("G").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, _
            CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        
        ' Populate inserted column 'G' with header and formulas.
        srg.Range("G1").Value = "Next Step"
        srg.Range("G2", srg.Cells(srg.Rows.Count, "G")).FormulaR1C1 = "" _
            & "=IF(RC[-1]="""",""Assessments_Clean_2""," _
            & "IF(RC[-1]<DATE(2023,7,1),""Delete""," _
            & "IF(RC[-1]>=DATE(2023,7,1),""Completed_Orig"")))"
        
        ' Convert all worksheet formulas to values.
        srg.Value = srg.Value
        
        Dim i As Long
    
        ' Delete entire rows if flagged 'Delete' in column 'G'.
        For i = srg.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
            With srg.Cells(i, "G")
                If .Value = "Delete" Then .EntireRow.Delete
            End With
        Next i
        
    End If
    
    ' Let the user see what it looks like before requiring the column input.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Require user to input a column number.
    
    Dim FilterColumn As Variant: FilterColumn = Application.InputBox( _
        Prompt:="Which column would you like to filter by?", _
        Title:="Filter column", Default:="1", Type:=1)
    
    If FilterColumn = False Then
        MsgBox "You canceled!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    FilterColumn = CLng(FilterColumn)
    
    If FilterColumn <= 0 Then
        MsgBox "Enter a valid column number!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If FilterColumn > srg.Columns.Count Then
        MsgBox "There are only " & srg.Columns.Count & " columns!", _
            vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Write the unique values from the column to a dictionary.
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim Value As Variant, j As Long
    
    For j = 2 To srg.Rows.Count
        Value = srg.Cells(j, FilterColumn).Value
        If Not IsError(Value) Then
            Value = CStr(Value)
            If Len(Value) > 0 Then
                If Not dict.Exists(Value) Then dict(Value) = Empty
            End If
        End If
    Next j
    
    If dict.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No valid values found!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Create or update worksheets according to the values in the dictionary.
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = sws.Parent
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet, Item As Variant
    
    For Each Item In dict.Keys
        srg.AutoFilter Field:=FilterColumn, Criteria1:=Item
        If Not sws.Evaluate("=ISREF('" & Item & "'!A1)") Then
            Set dws = wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
            dws.Name = Item ' valid name required!!!
        Else
            Set dws = wb.Sheets(Item)
            dws.Move After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
            dws.UsedRange.Clear
        End If
        srg.Copy dws.Range("A1")
        dws.Columns.AutoFit
    Next Item
    
    sws.AutoFilterMode = False
    sws.Activate
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Sheets created or updated.", vbInformation

End Sub
```